# Ember Data not serializing record id on save(), resulting in PUT with no id?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a route that creates a new record like so:

```
App.ServicesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('service');
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
    },

});
```

Then I bind that model's properties to the route's template using `{{input type="text" value=model.serviceId ... }}` which works great, the model gets populated as I fill up the form.

Then I save record:

```
App.ServicesNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions : {
        saveService : function() {
            this.get('model').save(); // => POST to '/services'
        }
    }
});
```

Which works too.

Then I click the save button again, now the save method does a PUT as expected since the model has an id set (id: 102):

[image]

But then when I look at the PUT request in Dev Tools, I see that the id attribute was not serialized:

[image]

As a result, a new instance is created in the backend instead of updating the existing one.

Please ignore the serviceId property, it is just a regular `string` property unrelated to the record id which should be named just `id`.

I don't know why the `id` is not being serialized... I cannot define an id property on the model of course since Ember Data will not allow it, it is implicit. So I don't know what I am missing...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems Ember data by default not putting the id in the payload for both POST and PUT. What I do, I add another properties in my model as an id but with a different name for example for post I use postId. And before save() i assign the id: postiD = post.id. Ember only prevent us from adding id as model properties. Other name is fine :D

Comment: check this out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521859/ember-js-rest-update-put-not-working)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The base JSONSerializer in Ember-Data only includes id in the payload when creating records. [See DS.JSONAdapter.serialize docs.](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html#toc_ids)

The URL the RestAdapter generates for PUTting the update includes the ID in the path.  In your case I believe it would be: `PUT '/services/102'`.

You can either extract it from the path in your backend service.  Or you should be able to override the behavior of your serializer to add the id like this:

```
App.ServiceSerializer = DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  serialize: function(record, options) {
    var json = this._super.apply(this, arguments); // Get default serialization

    json.id = record.id;  // tack on the id

    return json;
  }
});
```

There's plenty of additional info on serialization customization in the docs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: What if ember is trying to post its generated id to the backend

Answer (score 4):

Initially I used [ronco's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683275/ember-data-not-serializing-record-id-on-save-resulting-in-put-with-no-id/24685337#24685337) answer and it worked well.
But when I looked at ember data's source code I noticed that this option is supported natively. You just need to pass the includeId option to the serializer.
Example code:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    serialize: function(record, options) {
        options = options ? options : {}; // handle the case where options is undefined
        options.includeId = true;
        return this._super.apply(this, [record, options]); // Call the parent serializer
    }
});
```

This will also handle custom primary key definitions nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know it's a sync issue. After first request you do the post request and then, it has been saved in the server, when you click next time the store haven't got enough time to refresh itself. I've got similar issue when I've created something and immediately after that (without any transition or actions) I've tried to delete it - the error appears, in your case there's a little bit another story but with the same source. I think the solution is to refresh state after promise resolving.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not clicking too fast. I'm actually clicking manually, and waiting quite a bit between clicks. The id is clearly set on the record, but does not get serialized. This is such a basic failure (basically preventing all updates) that I cannot believe it is a problem in Ember. It must be me doing something wrong...

Comment: First of all I think it's strange to use this pattern: 

return this.store.createRecord('service', {serviceId: 123});

if you want to have an empty wrapper - it's ok, but what for you enter id explicitly - it should be generated by your backend and the should be serialised in the Ember Data Store.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, it was there for testing purposes only. :)