# Ember.js REST update (PUT) not working

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

My RESTFul GET, DELETE is working however the PUT (edit) strangely enough is fail to update the database:

Handlebar template for Post editing:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post">
<h1>View/Update Posts</h1>
{{#if isEditing}}
  <p>Title: {{input type="text" value=title}}</p>
  <p>Author: {{input type="text" value=author}}</p>
  <p>Body: {{textarea value=body}}</p>
  <button {{action 'doneEditing' this}}>Done</button>
{{else}}
  <p>Title : {{title}}</p>
  <p>Author: {{author}}</p>
  <p>Body  : {{body}}</p>
  <button {{action 'edit'}}>Edit</button>
{{/if}}
```

The PostController

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   isEditing: false,

   actions: {
      edit: function() {
         this.set('isEditing', true);
      },

      doneEditing: function(post) {
         this.set('isEditing', false);
         post.save(); //NOT WORKING - NOT UPDATING THE DATABASE RECORD!!!
      }
  }
});
```

REST adapter and data model

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string')
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   namespace: 'emberpostsrest/api'
});
```

Ember App URL

```
http://localhost/emberpostsrest
```

RESTFul server (using SLIM PHP)

```
http://localhost/emberpostsrest/api
```

Working REST

```
http://localhost/emberpostsrest/api/posts (GET all)
http://localhost/emberpostsrest/api/posts/1 (GET via id)
http://localhost/emberpostsrest/api/posts/1 (DELETE via id)
```

RESTFul API for edit already tested using PHP curl and is working fine:

```
//PUT - update
$data = array("id" => 3, "title" => "3", "author" => "2", "body" => "1");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data); 

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8080/emberpostsrest/api/posts/3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);
```

Slim PHP code

```
$app->put('/posts/:id', 'updatePostByID'); //update post via id

function updatePostByID($id) 
{
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $body = $request->getBody();
    $post = json_decode($body);
    $sql = "UPDATE posts 
            SET title = :title, 
                author = :author,
                body = :body
            WHERE id = :id";

    try 
    {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->bindParam("id", $post->id); 
        $stmt->bindParam("title", $post->title);
        $stmt->bindParam("author", $post->author);
        $stmt->bindParam("body", $post->body);
        $stmt->execute();
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

thank you for any help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect if you inspect the incoming data from Ember, you'll see that the values are keyed within the "posts" namespace.

In other words, instead of this:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "my title",
  "author": "me",
  "body": "the body"
}
```

It's coming in as this:

```
{
  "posts": {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "my title",
    "author": "me",
    "body": "the body"
  }
}
```

This is the convention for ember-data so you'll probably want to update your PHP code, rather than try to work around it on the Ember side.

Comment: that is sure extremely hard to check the json structure submitted to the PHP. Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer so I'm not sure. Can you log it out to the console or use a debugger when the request comes in?

Comment: I create a log writer in my REST function, this is the data: {"post":{"title":"Ember is the best","author":"rbk","body":"SPA Rock"}}. There is no ID lol

Comment: I solve it by adding another field in the Model call postID. Ember data is not allowing ID as field. So why it skip sending ID to the server for the Put while for delete it send the ID with it. Is this a bug or something?

Comment: The ID should already be present as a top level JSON value and you shouldn't need to add it to the model as postID.

Comment: Read comment no 3. From the log, there is no ID in json structure

Comment: After my editing, my CRUD update is working, by adding an ID attribute with a different name

Answer (score 1):

My solving code as suggested by @Beerlington, I log the json submitted from Ember to my PHP Rest function. This is the json object

```
{
  "post": {
    "title": "my title",
    "author": "me",
    "body": "the body"
  }
}
```

If you notice, there is no ID, which prevent the updating coz that one is primary key lol. So I update my Ember Model.

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
   postId: DS.attr('string'),
   title: DS.attr('string'),
   author: DS.attr('string'),
   body: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Notice postId not Id - Ember data not allow Id as model properties

The editing controller

```
doneEditing: function(post) {
  post.set("postId", post.id);
  post.save()
  this.set('isEditing', false);
}
```

And finally I update my PHP Rest function to handle the json structure as submitted by Ember

```
function updatePostByID($id) 
{
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $body = $request->getBody();
    $data = json_decode($body);

    //logging json data received from Ember!
    //$file = 'json.txt';
    //file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));

    $post = null;
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $postData = $value;
    }

    $post = new Post();
    foreach($postData as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "postId")
            $post->id = $value;

        if ($key == "title")
            $post->title = $value;

        if ($key == "author")
            $post->author = $value;

        if ($key == "body")
            $post->body = $value;   
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE posts 
            SET title = :title, 
                author = :author,
                body = :body
            WHERE id = :id";

    try 
    {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->bindParam("id", $post->id); 
        $stmt->bindParam("title", $post->title);
        $stmt->bindParam("author", $post->author);
        $stmt->bindParam("body", $post->body);
        $stmt->execute();
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```